# Xcode Mac OS X NSWindowTabbingMode tabs on part of the window

Tags: xcode, tabs, nswindow, macos-sierra

OS X Sierra introduces the ability for any NSWindow to have tabs. I like this but by default the tabs take the entire length of the window. How do I make it so it's like the screenshot below I made in photoshop where I have a sidebar and the tabs on the right side. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It looks like nested windows. In which window is the sidebar and the toolbar? Can't you use a tabview?

Comment: @Willeke I don't know how to nest windows - also if I disable the title bar the tabs will not appear

Comment: At the moment there isn't any API to customize tabbed windows.